# Difference between year-of-era and week-based-year?

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, java-time

Java 8's [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class has a method, `ofPattern(String pattern)`, that lets you define a format from a string of `A-z`, `a-z` letters. The examples don't clarify the difference between `y`, *year-of-era* and `Y`, *week-based-year*. What is it?

```
Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
------  -------                     ------------      -------
 y       year-of-era                 year              2004; 04
 Y       week-based-year             year              1996; 96
```

Comment: Such horrible docs in this case, ugh.

Comment: Just need to vent real quick that this API is terrible!

Answer (score 66):

That's year value for "year-week" style dates, as in 2006-W52.
It may be off the year-of-era value by +1 or -1 if the week in question straddles year boundary.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates

Comment: Correct answer. To explain, some applications track time by *whole* weeks, Monday to Sunday. The first week is defined as the week with the first Thursday of the year. The [first week of 2014](http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php) began on December 30, 2013, ending on January 5, 2014. So the week-year of both December 30 & 31, 2013 is `2014`.

Comment: Naming two different things with the same letter 'yy' vs 'YY' is an accident waiting to happen. It is like Y2K but every year.

Comment: Yup, my program teleported to 2020 a few days early and crashed and burned. Luckily no one was injured, and it's good to know I am not alone.

Comment: Haha, spotted the same bug today, luckiliy just in our test scenario's so no harm is done. But bug is indeed quickly made.

Answer (score 45):

## tl;dr

[image: table showing the calendar year of 2019-12-30 is 2019 while the week-based year is 2020]

[image: Table showing the length in days and weeks for a calendar year and a week-based year, 365 or 366 days versus 364 or 371, and 52 partial weeks versus 52 or 53 whole weeks.]

## Details

Some other Answers are quite interesting, but complicated. Here is a hopefully simpler Answer to get your oriented.

## `y` and `u` (lowercase)

The `y` character for year-of-era is simply the calendar year, the regular year used across the West and much of the world, based on the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar).

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class also uses a `u` for the nearly the same thing. For contemporary dates, there is no difference. For the nitty-gritty details, see [*`uuuu` versus `yyyy` in `DateTimeFormatter` formatting pattern codes in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41177442/642706).

For the regular dates we use in quotidian life, you would parse or generate text representing date values using a formatting pattern such as:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" ) ;
```

…or…

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
```

In either case, Monday, December 30, 2019 would be parsed like this:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "30/12/2019" ) ;
```

> localDate.toString(): 2019-12-30

## `Y` (uppercase)

Many people in various industries find it useful to track time by week, assigning a number to each week of the year.

There are various ways to define a week, such as starting on a Sunday or on a Monday. So there are various ways to define a week of the year. Does week # 1 have the January 1st? Or does week # 1 have the first Sunday of the year?

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard [defines a week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) as starting on a Monday. Week number 1 has the first Thursday of the new calendar year.

This definition means week-based year has either 52 or 53 whole weeks, always 7-days long (Monday-Sunday),for a year length of either 364 days or 371 days. In contrast, a calendar year has either 365 or 366 days crossing 52 partial weeks.

So the date 2019-12-30 (Monday, December 30, 2019) is actually in the first week of week-based year of 2020.

[image: calendar showing week # 1 of 2020, starting with December 30, 2019.]

- If you need to generate or parse the week-based year value of *2020*, use uppercase `YYYY` for that date of 2019-12-30 in your formatting pattern.
- If you want the calendar year of 2019-12-30, that is *2019*, use lowercase `yyyy`.

### ISO 8601 format

The ISO 8601 standard defines a specific format for representing a date within a week of a week-based year: YYYY-Www-d where the `YYYY` is the week-based year, the `-W` is fixed, the `ww` represents the week number 1-52 or 1-53, and the `d` represents a day-of-week running 1-7 for Monday-Sunday.

So Monday, December 30, 2019 is: `2020-W01-1` meaning week-based year 2020, first week of the year, and first day of the week (Monday).

To parse the ISO 8601 week with day-of-week number, we can use `DateTimeFormatter`. No need to define a formatting pattern with `YYYY`, as this work has already been done for you. Use the builtin [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_WEEK_DATE).

```
String output = localDate.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE ) ;
```

> 2020-W01-1

Likewise, parsing.

```
LocalDate localDate = 
    LocalDate.parse( 
        "2020-W01-1" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE
    )
;
```

> localDate.toString(): 2019-12-30

## *ThreeTen-Extra*

The [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library adds functionality to the *java.time* classes built into Java.

### `org.threeten.extra.YearWeek`

That library provides the `YearWeek` class. Just what you need if you are working with weeks of week-based year according to the [ISO 8601 definition of a week and week-based year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

This class can translate back and forth between the regular date format and the week-oriented format.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2019 , Month.DECEMBER , 30 ) ;  // Monday 2019-12-30. Its week-based year is 2020. 
YearWeek yearWeek = YearWeek.from( localDate ) ;
String wFormatted = yearWeek.toString() ;
```

> 2020-W01

Get a date from that.

```
LocalDate localDate = yearWeek.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
```

> localDate.toString(): 2019-12-30

Answer (score 10):

Each field is documented in a "field" class, such as `ChronoField`, `WeekFields` or `IsoFields`.

The "year-of-era" field is documented in [`ChronoField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#YEAR_OF_ERA).

The "week-based-year" field is documented in [`WeekFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekBasedYear--).

Answer (score 2):

What `Y` suggests is that we want to format a given date according to ISO 8601 week-numbering year. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates), the definition of week 01 is

> the week with the year's first Thursday in it (the formal ISO definition)

and thus,

> The first ISO week of a year may have up to three days that are actually in the Gregorian calendar year that is ending

Let's consider "2019-12-30" date, which is a Monday.

[image: calendar showing ISO 8601 weeks 1 & 2 of year-based year 2020]

If we take a look at that week, we have December 30 & 31 of 2019 are Monday and Tuesday; January 1-4 of 2020 are Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, and Saturday. As you can see, this week spans [Gregorian calendar year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) (a calendar system we use) 2019 and Gregorian calendar year 2020. If we apply definition of week01 of week-based year above, we can see that the week between 12/30/2019 and 01/05/2020 is week01 of week-based year 2020 (ISO standard specifies that [the beginning of a week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week) is Monday). Thus, if we want to parse "2019-12-30" with dateTimeFormatter `'YYYY-MM-dd'`, the correct result is `'2020-12-30'`. However, with `'yyyy-MM-dd'`, the end result will be `'2019-12-30'`.

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2019-12-30").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd"))); // output "2020-12-30"
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2019-12-30").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))); // output "2019-12-30"
```

I think there might be a potential problem with Java implementation. If we consider [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61064003/1460102) given by Sam Berry above, the output of "2019-12-29" doesn't consistent with how week-based year is defined. The reason is that "2019-12-29" is a Sunday. If we apply definition from Wikipedia above, "2019-12-29" should be parsed as "2019-12-29" even given `'YYYY-MM-dd'`. This is because beginning of week01 is Monday rather than Sunday by ISO standard. If we look up [week numbers for 2020](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2020), we can see week 01 of 2020 starts at "2019-12-30". I suspect this is possibly due to the implementer of API consider the beginning of a week is Sunday, which is not true according to ISO standard.

**UPDATE**

On the suspect of Java implementation error. It is not implementation error. Thanks for [Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v) comment below. During the formatting, there is subtle dependency on how the beginning of week01 is defined, which is relfected by `Locale`. For example, if the locale is europe, the beginning of a week is Monday, which is consistent with ISO standard. Thus

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2019, Month.DECEMBER, 29).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd", Locale.FRANCE)));
```

has output `2019-12-29`. However, in the U.S., the beginning of a week is considered as Sunday. Thus

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2019, Month.DECEMBER, 29).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd", Locale.US)));
```

has output `2020-12-29`.

Comment: Correction: It doesn’t necessarily adhere to ISO 9601 weeks. It depends on the week scheme of the locale of the formatter. `LocalDate.of(2020, Month.DECEMBER, 31).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Y", Locale.FRANCE))` yields 2020 in agreement with ISO 8601. If I use `Locale.US` instead, we get 2021 instead.

Comment: @OleV.V. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Based on your example, I think there is subtle dependency on how the beginning of a week defined. If `Locale.US`, since beginning of a week is considered as Sunday, thus "2019-12-29" is counted as part of week01 of 2020. However, if europe (`Locale.FRANCE`), since the beginning of a week is Monday consistent with ISO standard, we obtain "2020-12-29".

Comment: True so far. Also the minimal number of days in the first week takes part in deciding when the new week-based year begins. See the last paragraph of my new answer.

Comment: I see. So the check is two steps: 1) we first check how to define a week based on locale 2) we then check if such a week can be qualified as week 01 of a new year rather than the last week of previous year based on the week definition from step 1.

Comment: Seems like much grief could be avoided if we all avoided ever using the `YYYY-MM-dd` style for week-based year. Following ISO 8601, the date December 30, 2019 should be represented as either `2019-12-30` (calendar year) or `2020-W01-1` (week-based year)— but never a bastardized mix of the two.

Answer (score 1):

#### week based year

A concept where a week only belongs to 1 year. For example:

```
LocalDate.parse("2019-12-29").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/Y")) 
---> "12/29/2020"`
```

#### year of era

The common use of year, 1/1 always being the first day of the year. For example:

```
LocalDate.parse("2019-12-29").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/y"))
---> "12/29/2019"
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t find it perfectly clear from the other answers, so allow me to give my shot.

The *week-based year* or sometimes *week year* for short is the year that the relevant week number belongs to. So for example all of the days of week 1 have the same week-based year even if some of the week lies in the previous calendar year. Or the other way around, say that week 52 of a year stretches into the following year (which is possible with some, not all week numbering schemes), then every day of that week has the old calendar year as its week-based year. Where I live, week 1 of 2020 was from Monday December 30 to Sunday January 5, inclusive. So for the days up to December 29, calendar year and week-based year agreed to be 2019. December 30 and 31 had week-based year 2020, but of course still calendar year 2019. From January 1 calendar year and week-based year again agreed, now at 2020.

So the week-based year hardly has any meaningful use except together with a week number.

Where it gets a bit complicated (and where I think the other answers are not quite clear) is that week numbering is locale dependent, and therefore week-based year is too. A `DateTimeFormatter` has a locale and uses this locale for selecting the week numbering scheme to use when deciding the week-based year for a given date.

To illustrate I am formatting 10 days around New Year 2022 in three different locales:

1. I want to show ISO 8601 weeks and have chosen France as a country that follows ISO
2. US weeks begin on Sundays
3. In many Arabic countries the new week begins on Saturday; I have taken Morocco as an example

My code:

```
    DateTimeFormatter iso
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Y w E", Locale.FRANCE);
    DateTimeFormatter us
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Y w E", Locale.US);
    DateTimeFormatter arabic = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("Y w E", Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-MA"));
    
    System.out.println("                ISO           US          Morocco");
    LocalDate d = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.DECEMBER, 25);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.format("%-10s  %-12s  %-11s  %s%n",
                d, d.format(iso), d.format(us), d.format(arabic));
        d = d.plusDays(1);
    }
```

Output:

```
                ISO           US          Morocco
2021-12-25  2021 51 sam.  2021 52 Sat  2021 53 السبت
2021-12-26  2021 51 dim.  2022 1 Sun   2021 53 الأحد
2021-12-27  2021 52 lun.  2022 1 Mon   2021 53 الاثنين
2021-12-28  2021 52 mar.  2022 1 Tue   2021 53 الثلاثاء
2021-12-29  2021 52 mer.  2022 1 Wed   2021 53 الأربعاء
2021-12-30  2021 52 jeu.  2022 1 Thu   2021 53 الخميس
2021-12-31  2021 52 ven.  2022 1 Fri   2021 53 الجمعة
2022-01-01  2021 52 sam.  2022 1 Sat   2022 1 السبت
2022-01-02  2021 52 dim.  2022 2 Sun   2022 1 الأحد
2022-01-03  2022 1 lun.   2022 2 Mon   2022 1 الاثنين
```

Observations;

- In all three columns the week year changes on the same day as week 1 begins.
- That change happens on different dates in the three locales:

  1. In the US week-based year 2022 begins on St. Stephen’s Day 2021.
  2. In Morocco week-based year 2022 happens to begin on the first day of calendar year 2022, but only because in 2022 that day is a Saturday and therefore the first day of the week.
  3. In ISO 8601 week-based year 2022 doesn’t begin until January 3.

For the sake of completeness: Defining week numbering has two parts:

1. On which day-of-week does a new week start
2. How many days of the new year must a week include to qualify as week 1. This is called *the minimal number of days in the first week.*.

In both US and Morocco week 1 is defined as the week containing January 1. In other words, a week just needs to have at least 1 day in the new year for it to be week 1 of that new year. Not so in ISO. You see that January 1 in France belongs to week 52 of the old year. Here a week belongs to the year where the majority of its days lie (since there are 7 days in a week, an odd number, there will never be a tie). In other words, a week must have at least 4 (four) of its days in the new year for it to be week 1.

Answer (score 0):

I like @xxks-kkk answer. If you are interesting which week definition is used for your Locale, you can check it easily.

In brief:

Definition of the week and to which year it belongs to depends on two values:

- The first day-of-week.
- The minimal number of days in the first week.

This two values are encapsulated in `WeekFields` class.

The following code prints all possible `WeekFields` with all assigned to it `Locale`s.

```java
public class PrintLocaleWeekFields {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<WeekFields, List<Locale>> locales = Arrays.stream(Locale.getAvailableLocales())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(WeekFields::of));
        System.out.println(locales);
    }
}
```

Printed result:

```
WeekFields[MONDAY,1]=[tk_TM_#Latn, en_NU, ff_LR_#Adlm, es_BO, bs_BA, en_LR, ar_TD, nus_SS_#Latn, ff_MR_#Latn, sw_UG, tk_TM, sr_ME_#Cyrl, os_GE_#Cyrl, yo_NG, en_PW, sr_CS, agq_CM_#Latn, ar_EH, bs_BA_#Latn, dje_NE, hy_AM_#Armn, ff_GH_#Latn, fr_PM, ar_KM, agq_CM, tr_TR, kl_GL_#Latn, ar_MR, kl_GL, en_NR, rw_RW_#Latn, en_CY, tr_TR_#Latn, ti_ER, nus_SS, en_RW, hr_HR_#Latn, ln_CD, nnh_CM, dje_NE_#Latn, ksf_CM, fr_VU, nnh_CM_#Latn, fr_NE, bez_TZ_#Latn, ksb_TZ, ln_CF, en_CX, ak_GH_#Latn, en_TZ, fr_NC, fr_CM, pcm_NG_#Latn, teo_UG, ln_CG, az_AZ, el_CY, ku_TR, ff_SN, sq_MK, sr_BA_#Cyrl, so_SO_#Latn, tr_CY, lv_LV_#Latn, uz_UZ_#Latn, dua_CM, fr_TN, sr_RS, sw_TZ_#Latn, fr_PF, pt_GQ, vun_TZ, jmc_TZ, mg_MG_#Latn, en_TV, en_PN, lu_CD_#Latn, en_GY, dyo_SN, nl_CW, fr_GQ, en_NG, fr_CI, ia_001, en_LC, ff_BF_#Adlm, bm_ML_#Latn, yav_CM_#Latn, mk_MK, sl_SI, sg_CF_#Latn, jgo_CM, ff_NE_#Adlm, en_BM, kea_CV, vi_VN, mfe_MU, fr_BF, fr_YT, ff_CM_#Latn, sr_BA_#Latn, uk_UA_#Cyrl, ff_GW_#Adlm, ha_GH, yi_001_#Hebr, to_TO_#Latn, ff_GW_#Latn, mua_CM_#Latn, nyn_UG, ms_MY, rn_BI_#Latn, ta_LK, tg_TJ, vun_TZ_#Latn, es_EC, mk_MK_#Cyrl, ff_CM_#Adlm, lg_UG, ff_NE_#Latn, cgg_UG, pcm_NG, en_BI, mi_NZ, ar_ER, es_EA, fr_SC, en_SL, ff_NG_#Latn, ff_NG_#Adlm, en_SH, eo_001, en_SI, vai_LR_#Vaii, rof_TZ_#Latn, ar_LB, ff_GN, eo_001_#Latn, hr_HR, rof_TZ, mn_MN, en_FM, fr_WF, ff_GM_#Latn, teo_UG_#Latn, asa_TZ_#Latn, bez_TZ, ff_GN_#Latn, sl_SI_#Latn, en_FK, bas_CM_#Latn, en_DG, pt_ST, ak_GH, es_419, ln_CD_#Latn, kkj_CM_#Latn, es_IC, ar_TN, bm_ML, jmc_TZ_#Latn, khq_ML, en_SB, rw_RW, shi_MA_#Tfng, ro_MD, uz_UZ, ia_001_#Latn, en_SC, en_UG, en_NZ, es_UY, ru_UA, sg_CF, en_BB, hr_BA, yo_NG_#Latn, lu_CD, ar_001, so_SO, lv_LV, sr_RS_#Cyrl, en_LS, ka_GE, sw_TZ, fr_RW, mg_MG, sr_RS_#Latn, ky_KG, tzm_MA_#Latn, ku_TR_#Latn, mfe_MU_#Latn, ky_KG_#Cyrl, qu_EC, ka_GE_#Geor, en_MS, kde_TZ_#Latn, sr_ME, en_ZM, fr_ML, ha_NG, os_GE, yi_001, en_GH, tzm_MA, ses_ML, rwk_TZ_#Latn, vai_LR_#Latn, sw_CD, ff_MR_#Adlm, en_VC, ses_ML_#Latn, en_150, ha_NE, en_KN, ro_RO, sr_ME_#Latn, ff_LR_#Latn, bas_CM, fr_MG, es_CL, sq_AL, ro_RO_#Latn, twq_NE, nmg_CM, en_MP, en_GD, sbp_TZ_#Latn, kde_TZ, ta_MY, si_LK_#Sinh, en_KI, twq_NE_#Latn, sq_AL_#Latn, ff_GH_#Adlm, fr_MF, en_SZ, rwk_TZ, kk_KZ, ar_PS, kkj_CM, es_GQ, en_SX, ru_KZ, ko_KP, nl_SR, bem_ZM_#Latn, cgg_UG_#Latn, nl_BQ, ee_GH_#Latn, ff_GN_#Adlm, uz_UZ_#Cyrl, asa_TZ, fr_SN, fr_MA, ff_GM_#Adlm, fr_BL, mgo_CM, nmg_CM_#Latn, tg_TJ_#Cyrl, en_SS, shi_MA, en_MG, fr_BI, naq_NA_#Latn, fr_BJ, vai_LR, bs_BA_#Cyrl, khq_ML_#Latn, mn_MN_#Cyrl, wo_SN, ha_NG_#Latn, fr_HT, nl_SX, fr_CG, ms_MY_#Latn, zgh_MA_#Tfng, nyn_UG_#Latn, en_VU, to_TO, ff_SL_#Latn, xog_UG_#Latn, ff_SN_#Adlm, vi_VN_#Latn, jgo_CM_#Latn, zgh_MA, uk_UA, lg_UG_#Latn, en_NF, sr_XK_#Cyrl, ar_SS, nl_AW, en_AI, xog_UG, en_CM, ru_MD, ff_SN_#Latn, en_TO, ff_SL_#Adlm, en_PG, fr_CF, pt_TL, en_ER, sr_BA, be_BY_#Cyrl, fr_TG, sr_XK_#Latn, ig_NG, fr_GN, en_CK, ar_MA, fr_TD, bem_ZM, ewo_CM_#Latn, ewo_CM, fr_CD, rn_BI, en_NA, mgo_CM_#Latn, lag_TZ, qu_BO, kea_CV_#Latn, sq_XK, mi_NZ_#Latn, en_KY, si_LK, ar_SO, fr_MU, en_TK, mua_CM, pt_GW, ee_TG, ln_AO, be_BY, pt_CV, ru_BY, ee_GH, kk_KZ_#Cyrl, yo_BJ, fr_KM, es_AR, en_MY, sbp_TZ, hy_AM, en_GM, ksb_TZ_#Latn, pt_AO, en_001, dua_CM_#Latn, lag_TZ_#Latn, ru_KG, fr_MR, ksf_CM_#Latn, ff_BF_#Latn, en_MW, naq_NA, en_IO, en_CC, az_AZ_#Cyrl, shi_MA_#Latn, es_CU, ig_NG_#Latn, yav_CM, da_GL, wo_SN_#Latn, es_CR, fr_GA, en_MU, az_AZ_#Latn, dyo_SN_#Latn, en_VG, en_TC, af_NA, mas_TZ, ms_BN],
WeekFields[SATURDAY,1]=[ar_EG, ps_AF_#Arab, ar_SY, uz_AF, lrc_IR, ar_OM, lrc_IQ, ar_DZ, fa_IR_#Arab, fr_DJ, so_DJ, lrc_IR_#Arab, ar_AE, mzn_IR, en_SD, uz_AF_#Arab, ar_IQ, ar_KW, ar_JO, fr_DZ, fa_AF, ckb_IQ_#Arab, ar_SD, fa_IR, kab_DZ_#Latn, kab_DZ, ps_AF, mzn_IR_#Arab, en_AE, ar_BH, ar_QA, ar_EG_#Arab, ckb_IQ, ckb_IR, ar_LY, fr_SY, ar_DJ],
WeekFields[MONDAY,4]=[se_NO_#Latn, dsb_DE, lb_LU_#Latn, se_NO, pl_PL, nds_DE, nb_SJ, lb_LU, dsb_DE_#Latn, is_IS_#Latn, no_NO_NY, pl_PL_#Latn, nds_DE_#Latn, tt_RU, fur_IT_#Latn, ast_ES_#Latn, en_JE, da_DK_#Latn, en_AT, gd_GB, wae_CH_#Latn, no_NO_#Latn, smn_FI_#Latn, en_NL, gsw_FR, hu_HU, bg_BG_#Cyrl, et_EE, fy_NL, de_IT, de_CH, nl_NL, pt_CH, gv_IM, kw_GB_#Latn, fi_FI_#Latn, fr_BE, nb_NO, it_SM, fi_FI, ca_FR, de_BE, de_DE_#Latn, fr_FR_#Latn, ksh_DE, ru_RU, ga_IE, rm_CH_#Latn, fr_LU, ga_GB, no_NO, de_LU, de_DE, nn_NO_#Latn, en_DK, lt_LT, ksh_DE_#Latn, da_DK, en_BE, tt_RU_#Cyrl, ga_IE_#Latn, is_IS, en_SE, gsw_LI, kw_GB, en_DE, en_FI, sah_RU_#Cyrl, en_FJ, de_LI, smn_FI, de_AT, ce_RU, os_RU, nl_NL_#Latn, gl_ES_#Latn, en_GG, sv_SE, el_GR_#Grek, it_VA, es_ES, bg_BG, hsb_DE, eu_ES_#Latn, sv_SE_#Latn, sv_FI, en_IE, fo_FO_#Latn, en_GB, fr_MC, ce_RU_#Cyrl, gsw_CH, pt_LU, hsb_DE_#Latn, br_FR_#Latn, es_ES_#Latn, cy_GB_#Latn, fr_FR, sah_RU, sk_SK, ru_RU_#Cyrl, gv_IM_#Latn, nds_NL, fr_RE, fr_GP, fr_CH, nb_NO_#Latn, fy_NL_#Latn, cs_CZ, ca_ES, hu_HU_#Latn, rm_CH, et_EE_#Latn, gd_GB_#Latn, se_FI, lt_LT_#Latn, ca_IT, ca_AD, it_CH, it_IT, nn_NO, se_SE, it_IT_#Latn, wae_CH, fo_DK, en_CH, fo_FO, ast_ES, fr_MQ, fur_IT, fr_GF, sk_SK_#Latn, eu_ES, el_GR, ca_ES_VALENCIA, gl_ES, en_IM, gsw_CH_#Latn, en_GI, ca_ES_#Latn, nl_BE, cy_GB, sv_AX, cs_CZ_#Latn, br_FR],
WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]=[, he, th_TH_#Thai, nds, ti_ET, ta_SG, lv, zh_SG_#Hans, en_JM, kkj, sd__#Arab, dz_BT, mni, yi, cs, el, af, smn, dsb, khq, ne_IN, es_US, sa, en_US_POSIX, pt_MO, zh__#Hans, so_KE, gu_IN_#Gujr, teo, eu, es_DO, ru, az, su__#Latn, fa, nd, kk, hy, en_AU, ksb, luo, lb, su, no, ar_IL, mgh, or_IN, az__#Latn, ta, lag, luo_KE_#Latn, bo, om_KE, en_AS, zh_TW, sd_IN, kln, mai, pt_MZ, my_MM_#Mymr, gl, sr__#Cyrl, yue_CN_#Hans, ff__#Adlm, kn_IN, ga, qu, en_PR, mua, jv, ps, sn, km, zgh, es, jgo, gsw, pa_IN_#Guru, ur_PK_#Arab, ceb, bn_BD_#Beng, ne_NP_#Deva, te, sl, mr_IN, ha, guz_KE_#Latn, es_HN, sbp, sw, nmg, pt_BR_#Latn, vai__#Vaii, gu, lo, zh_HK_#Hans, bs__#Latn, os, am, ki_KE, en_PK, zh_CN, rw, brx_IN, en_TT, dav, ses, xh_ZA, es_VE, mer_KE, mg, mr, seh, mgo, en_US, pa__#Guru, sa_IN_#Deva, gu_IN, ast, mt_MT_#Latn, yue__#Hans, ccp_BD_#Cakm, ks__#Arab, af_ZA_#Latn, ti_ET_#Ethi, am_ET_#Ethi, cgg, zh_MO, ksf, cy, ceb_PH, sq, fr, qu_PE, de, zu_ZA, su_ID_#Latn, lg, en_DM, sd, he_IL_#Hebr, yue_CN, en_WS, so, kab, nus, sn_ZW, th_TH_TH_#u-nu-thai, hi, zh_MO_#Hant, vai, sd_PK_#Arab, mi, mt, yav, kam, ro, ps_PK, ee, en_UM, lo_LA, chr, af_ZA, doi, es_BZ, as, it, ks_IN, my_MM, ur_PK, ii, naq, en_SG, kln_KE, tzm, fur, om, mai_IN_#Deva, ja_JP_JP_#u-ca-japanese, es_SV, pt_BR, mni_IN_#Beng, ml_IN, hr, lt, ccp, zh_CN_#Hans, en, guz_KE, ccp_BD, ca, pa_PK, ug_CN, ki_KE_#Latn, es_BR, bo_CN_#Tibt, chr_US, nyn, mk, sat, pa__#Arab, bs, fy, th, dav_KE, dje, mas_KE, mni_IN, ckb, bem, da, wae, ig, en_HK, brx_IN_#Deva, mer_KE_#Latn, en_US_#Latn, ki, nb, kok, ewo, nn, bg, kea, zu, am_ET, bo_CN, hsb, kok_IN_#Deva, sat_IN, pcm, sah, mer, br, ar_SA, fil_PH_#Latn, sk, om_ET_#Latn, ml, en_MT, en_IL, sv, kn_IN_#Knda, lkt_US, sd__#Deva, ku, fil_PH, es_PH, es_CO, agq, ebu, es_GT, nd_ZW_#Latn, mn, kam_KE, en_MO, ja_JP_#Jpan, wo, shi__#Tfng, en_BZ, lkt_US_#Latn, ta_IN_#Taml, az__#Cyrl, tk, shi__#Latn, en_BW, he_IL, nd_ZW, luy_KE_#Latn, mni__#Beng, ne, zh_SG, om_ET, lo_LA_#Laoo, ja_JP, kam_KE_#Latn, my, ka, ko_KR_#Kore, ms_ID, shi, kl, sa_IN, yue_HK, id, zh, es_PE, mgh_MZ, saq, zh_HK_#Hant, sat_IN_#Olck, es_PA, bez, kw, vai__#Latn, ksh, ur_IN, ln, luy_KE, pt, mgh_MZ_#Latn, ar_YE, to, et, rof, en_BS, be, gv, kln_KE_#Latn, dua, hi_IN_#Deva, guz, en_KE, mfe, ja, or, brx, mai_IN, ko_KR, es_MX, zu_ZA_#Latn, doi_IN, fi, uz, bs__#Cyrl, sr__#Latn, bo_IN, rm, bn, kn, nnh, bn_BD, en_ZA, pa_IN, en_MH, zh__#Hant, jv_ID_#Latn, ky, mas, xh_ZA_#Latn, dav_KE_#Latn, xh, te_IN, mas_KE_#Latn, lrc, ce, mt_MT, ko, ml_IN_#Mlym, ak, kde, dz, ia, seh_MZ, su_ID, ii_CN, pa_PK_#Arab, bn_IN, pa, rwk, rn, tg, hu, ceb_PH_#Latn, twq, bm, en_GU, tr, es_PY, kok_IN, dz_BT_#Tibt, en_PH, zh_MO_#Hans, sat__#Olck, ff, haw_US_#Latn, en_AG, ebu_KE, xog, ms, ug, qu_PE_#Latn, id_ID, teo_KE, haw_US, vi, fr_CA, dyo, luo_KE, eo, en_ZW, pl, ur, uz__#Arab, saq_KE, se, sn_ZW_#Latn, ms_SG, yue__#Hant, km_KH_#Khmr, luy, uk, es_PR, mzn, tt, ug_CN_#Arab, hi_IN, saq_KE_#Latn, asa, ff__#Latn, doi_IN_#Deva, ebu_KE_#Latn, uz__#Cyrl, fil, yue_HK_#Hant, fo, ne_NP, ta_IN, lkt, id_ID_#Latn, is, te_IN_#Telu, si, jv_ID, ks, zh_TW_#Hant, as_IN, zh_HK, sw_KE, th_TH, as_IN_#Beng, jmc, yue, ar, en_VI, haw, bas, uz__#Latn, sg, km_KH, nl, ks_IN_#Arab, sd_IN_#Deva, mr_IN_#Deva, sr, seh_MZ_#Latn, en_CA, gd, chr_US_#Cher, or_IN_#Orya, so_ET, vun, en_IN, lu, yo, es_NI, ii_CN_#Yiii, sd_PK, ti, ccp_IN],
WeekFields[SUNDAY,4]=[pt_PT]}
```

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy. You can do basically what you did on your previous answer. I should also point out that if a majority of your answers link to your own content, that can be considered as spam as well, so you shouldn't do that too much.