# Java 8 DateFormatter week of month and year key symbols difference

Tags: java, time, java-time

I am new to `java.time`. Please, be patient. What is the difference between

```
  Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
  ------  -------                     ------------      -------
    F       week-of-month               number            3
    W       week-of-month               number            4
```

isn't it just

```
  Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
  ------  -------                     ------------      -------
    F/W       week-of-month               number            3
```

and

```
  Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
  ------  -------                     ------------      -------
   Y       week-based-year             year              1996; 96
   u       year                        year              2004; 04
   y       year-of-era                 year              2004; 04
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: You ~never want to use `Y` instead of `y`, or you'll probably suffer the same outage that took down Twitter: http://www.juandebravo.com/2015/04/10/java-yyyy-date-format/

Comment: Good link. What about `u` and `F` and `W`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `u` and `y` has already been addressed: [What is the difference between year and year-of-era?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014225/what-is-the-difference-between-year-and-year-of-era)

#### Difference between `W` and `F`

There is [a bug in the javadoc for `F`](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8169482).

`W` is the week of month, as represented by [`Weekfields::weekOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekOfMonth--):

> This represents the concept of the count of weeks within the month where weeks start on a fixed day-of-week, such as Monday.

`F` is the aligned day of week in month, as represented by [`ChronoField.ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH):

> This represents the concept of the count of days within the period of a week where the weeks are aligned to the start of the month.

`F` behaves similarly in `DateTimeFormatter` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

**Example:** if you use 2016-11-07 as an input, `W` will return 2 (2nd week of the month) but `F` will return 7 (7th day of the first aligned week, which starts on the 1st of the month).

Comment: so, `2016-11-08` yields 1 for `F`? is there also smth like `aligned_week_number`?

Comment: Yes. I don't think so.

Comment: There is no letter for ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH or ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR, but the value can be output via `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`

Comment: If it doesn't turn up in the public system in the next month, ping me