# What does DateTimeFormatter parse LocalDate.of(0,1,5) to "010105"?

Tags: java-8, java-time

When using `DateTimeFormatter` of format `"yyMMdd"`, strange things happen... `LocaleDate.of(0,1,5)` is formatted to `"010105"`, but "000105" is correctly parsed to `LocalDate.of(2015, 1, 5)`. Why is that??

For testing:

```
@Test
public void testYear2000() {
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(0, 1, 5);
    String format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMdd").format(localDate);

    assertThat(format, is("000105")); // fail! it is "010105"

    LocalDate parse = LocalDate.parse("000105", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMdd"));

    assertThat(parse, is(LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 5))); //pass
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion comes from the fact that here:

```
LocalDate.of(0, 1, 5);
```

you have specified year zero, which is millenniums before the year of 2000:

```
LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 5);
```

The last will output `000105`.

**Update:** @Meno Hochschild added further explanations and I would also link [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014225/what-is-the-difference-between-year-and-year-of-era) nice question for reference.

Answer (score 4):

I add the supplementary explanation for the correct answer of @Lachezar Balev. Printing the year 0 (more than two thousand years ago) by the pattern yy means: Use **the two-digit-form of year-of-era equivalent to proleptic gregorian year 0 which is 1 BCE**. Therefore you see the year 1 in formatted output 010105.

If you had used the pattern uuMMdd (u=proleptic gregorian year) then the output would indeed match your expectation 000105 but is still fundementally wrong due to wrong input.