# DateTimeFormatter invalid day gets adapted after LocalDateTime.parse

Tags: java, datetime

I have been struggling with how java 8 handles the parsing of a String into an instance of `LocalDateTime`. I have noticed it when I was writing an unit test for that conversion from String to `LocalDateTime`.

Here below is a method example (not actual) which I have been used for a while since java 8 got released.

```
private void convertToLocalDateTime(String s) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-M-d HH:mm")
        .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
    try {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(s, formatter);
        System.out.println("s: " + s + " -> ldt: " + ldt.toString());
    } catch(DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("s: " + s + " -> The field is not a valid date.");
    }
}
```

Here, you can see that I have added two `s.o.p`'s to show you the display. Here is an display example;

```
s: 2016-06-31 11:00 -> ldt: 2016-06-30T11:00
s: 2016-07-31 11:00 -> ldt: 2016-07-31T11:00
s: 2016-08-31 11:00 -> ldt: 2016-08-31T11:00
s: 2016-09-31 11:00 -> ldt: 2016-09-30T11:00
s: 2016-10-31 11:00 -> ldt: 2016-10-31T11:00
s: 2016-11-31 11:00 -> ldt: 2016-11-30T11:00
s: 2016-12-31 11:00 -> ldt: 2016-12-31T11:00
s: 2016-11-0 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-11-1 11:00 -> ldt: 2016-11-01T11:00
s: 2016-11-15 11:00 -> ldt: 2016-11-15T11:00
s: 2016-11-30 11:00 -> ldt: 2016-11-30T11:00
s: 2016-11-31 11:00 -> ldt: 2016-11-30T11:00
s: 2016-11-32 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
```

As you can see everything seems correct, however the dates with days that is 1 day incorrect (eg 31 November) gets converted to **30** November. I was quite baffled because I've been using this approach the whole time and I *just* noticed that today.

After doing some research, I found out that there is a "resolver style". Here is a text from the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String)

> `public static DateTimeFormatter ofPattern(String pattern)`
>   Creates a formatter using the specified pattern.
>   This method will create a formatter based on a simple pattern of letters and symbols as described in the class documentation. For example, d MMM uuuu will format 2011-12-03 as '3 Dec 2011'.
>
> The formatter will use the default FORMAT locale. This can be changed using withLocale(Locale) on the returned formatter Alternatively use the ofPattern(String, Locale) variant of this method.
>
> The returned formatter has no override chronology or zone. **It uses SMART resolver style.**

I was like "wut". Apparently, there are [three resolver styles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.htm): STRICT, SMART and LENIENT.

So, I went with the `STRICT`. The first line in the body of the `convertToLocalDateTime(String)` method is modified with

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-M-d HH:mm")
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
```

Yet this gives the following

```
s: 2016-01-31 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-02-31 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-03-31 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-04-31 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-05-31 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-06-31 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-07-31 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-08-31 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-09-31 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-10-31 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-11-31 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-12-31 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-11-0 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-11-1 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-11-15 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-11-30 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-11-31 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
s: 2016-11-32 11:00 -> The field is not a valid date.
```

These all suddenly doesn't work. Even using `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` doesn't help. I suspect the STRICT doesn't work with custom format strings very well...

So, my question is: Is there a way to overcome the "*31 november*" issue, that it does **not** get resolved to 30 november? (and ofc similar for other possible dates) Or a way to return false if the resolver has adjusted the values?

Or do I have to evaluate the resulting `LocalDateTime` instance myself?

Comment: Ah, my google fu has failed me today...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion is justified.  I find that in fact a `DateTimeFormatter` for pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"`, using the `STRICT` resolver style, rejects even date strings that it formatted itself.

Upon further investigation, this seems to be related to `DateTimeFormatter`'s new (relative to the well-established `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`) distinction between "year" and "year of era".  With `DateTimeFormatter`, the `'y'` format symbol represents *the latter*; the former corresponds to format letter `'u'`.  It turns out that if I use the format string `"uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm"` that your program produces the output you seem to be looking for:

```
private void convertToLocalDateTime(String s) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-M-d HH:mm")
        .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
    try {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(s, formatter);
        System.out.println("s: " + s + " -> ldt: " + ldt.toString());
    } catch(DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("s: " + s + " -> The field is not a valid date.");
    }
}
```

Single-digit *vs.* double-digit fields does not make a difference for parsing.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014225/what-is-the-difference-between-year-and-year-of-era) addresses the difference between "year" and "year of era".  Whereas I understand the distinction, I think it was a poor choice to implement `DateTimeFormatter` with such unnecessary incompatibility with `SimpleDateFormat` for some of their most common uses.  I think I would have swapped the meaning of `'u'` and '`y`', so as to avoid exactly the kind of problem you've run into.  Evidently, however, the designers of this API disagreed, and that's all water under the bridge at this point.