# Nested exception is java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '3030821'

Tags: java

How can I parse this String

```
3030821
```

to date like

```
303-08-21
```

I mean AD year (Anno Domini),

I would also like this solution to be resistant to String like `20200820`

Comment: `3030-08-21` try this

Comment: @SwapnilPadaya it's not correct answer

Comment: Do you mean year 303 of the Common Era (CE or AD)? If not, what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("3030821", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuMMdd"));
        System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-MM-dd")));

        date = LocalDate.parse("20200820", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuMMdd"));
        System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-MM-dd")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
303-08-21
2020-08-20
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: I would also like this solution to be resistant to String like 20200820

Comment: @erickson - Got it! Thank you for the suggestion. Reverted to the original solution.

Comment: For other visitors to this answer, I found the following helpful: [What is the difference between `u` and `y` (and `Y`) in those datetime formatter strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014225/what-is-the-difference-between-year-and-year-of-era).