# Java analog of time.Parse from GoLang

Tags: java, date, datetime, parsing, datetime-format

I am rewriting piece of GO code to java and I have doubths about the following snippet.

Go code:

```
time.Parse("20060102", someString);
```

Is it analog of ?

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(credElements[0], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it?

Comment: That is a `LocalDate`, not a `ZonedDateTime`. There is neither a zone nor a time in that string.

Comment: What is the resulting type/value in Go and what do you expect/want it to be in Java? Looks like @Sweeper is right, the result might just be a *date* without *time (of day)*, offset or zone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick look at the [Go documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time) reveals that:

> A `Time` represents an instant in time with nanosecond precision.

Which is similar to Java's `Instant` type.

Also, from the docs of [`Parse`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Parse),

> Elements omitted from the layout are assumed to be zero or, when zero is impossible, one, so parsing "3:04pm" returns the time corresponding to Jan 1, year 0, 15:04:00 UTC (note that because the year is 0, this time is before the zero Time).
>
> [...]
>
> In the absence of a time zone indicator, Parse returns a time in UTC.

Knowing this, we can first create a `LocalDate` from your string that does not contain any zone or time information, then "assume" (as the Go documentation calls it) that it is at the start of day, and at the UTC zone, in order to convert it to an `Instant`:

```
var date = LocalDate.parse(someString, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
var instant = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
```

Comment: To avoid problems, you should use `date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash What problems could there be? The start of day is calculated with `LocalDate`, which is very “well behaved”, and not using any time zones, where the start of day could be non-00:00:00.

Comment: This is a great answer. The only thing I was concerned about was that `LocalDate#atStartOfDay()` uses the system's time and theoretically, it may not be always `00:00`. Thanks for updating it in your answer.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks. I usually only use those built-in ones for formatting, because I never made an effort to remember what the exact formats of those look like. Totally didn't know there was a built-in one for this format.

Answer (score 2):

Since the result of the line of Go you provided includes an offset, a zone and the time of day, you will have to explicitly attach those and use a specific formatter in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input
    String date = "20060102";
    // parse the date first, using a built-in formatter
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
    // then add the minimum time of day and the desired zone id
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(localDate, LocalTime.MIN, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    // the formatter
    DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z VV", Locale.ENGLISH);
    // the result of the Go statement
    String expected = "2006-01-02 00:00:00 +0000 UTC";
    // print the result
    System.out.println("Expected: " + expected);
    System.out.println("Actual:   " + zdt.format(dtfOut));
}
```

Output:

```
Expected: 2006-01-02 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
Actual:   2006-01-02 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

---

Posts about `y` and `u` (actually accepted answers to the questions)

- [`uuuu` versus `yyyy` in `DateTimeFormatter` formatting pattern codes in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41182911/1712135)
- [What is the difference between year and year-of-era?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29014580/1712135)

Comment: I have couple of questions.
1. Why do you use "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z VV" ?
2. String pattern = "uuuuMMdd";  is it typo ? I am about uuuu

Comment: @gstackoverflow - `u` is correct. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573 to learn more about it. Probably he has used `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z VV` to show you formatted output.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash though the golang `Time` type doesn’t support negative years :)

Comment: @gstackoverflow A `DateTimeFormatter` can be used for parsing `String`s as well as formatting date-time types as `String`. The longer pattern is the one responsible for the output, the shorter one parses your date `String`. [`u` is year, `y` is year of era](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Depending on your needs, `y` may be more appropriate to use, that's a thing you have to find out yourself.

Comment: @Sweeper - "... golang Time type doesn’t support negative years ..." - Note that the OP is migrating his code to Java and that's why `u` becomes so important in this code. His existing data may not have a negative year but his Java application may get date-time with a negative year.