# Simpledateformat symmetrical formatting/parsing

Tags: java, date, datetime

I try to format a timestamp using a `SimpleDateFormat` and also I try to use the same format to parse such a formatted date:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, YYYY 'at' hh:mma z");
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.US);
sdf.setTimeZone(cal.getTimeZone())

sdf.parse(sdf.format(1435271907000L)).getTime() == 1435271907000L
```

the last expression is false, the actual result is `1419806280000L`

So how is it possible to achive a symmetrical dateTimeFormat parsing/formatting behaviour?

Comment: Can you explain what you are using week year `YYYY` and why stripping off the seconds part? You cannot achieve the same result with these two things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no seconds in your format pattern, so your date's seconds will be initialized to 0. Second: [`YYYY` is different from `yyyy`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26431882/1700321).

Add `ss` to your pattern and change `YYYY` to `yyyy`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d ss, yyyy 'at' hh:mma z");

String f = sdf.format(1435271907000L);
Date d = sdf.parse(f);

System.out.println(d.getTime() == 1435271907000L);
```

Note it will also print `false` for time with milliseconds > 0 (e.g. `1435271907001L`). If you need milliseconds precision then you need to add milliseconds `SSS` to your pattern as well.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d ss SSS, yyyy 'at' hh:mma z");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try thi by correcting the cases of MMM and HH,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy 'at' HH:mm:ss.a`Z`");
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.US);
sdf.setTimeZone(cal.getTimeZone())
sdf.parse(sdf.format(1435271907000L)).getTime() == 1435271907000L
```

I hope this will work.