# Why does Java's java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter#format(LocalDateTime) add a year?

Tags: java, time, localization, utc, datetimeformatter

This is the code:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1451438792953L), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
String output = dateTimeFormatter.format(localDateTime);
```

This is the value of `localDateTime`:

```
2015-12-30T01:26:32.953
```

This is the value of `output`:

```
2016-12-30T01:26:32.953Z
```

Why does it add a year?

In `java.time.temporal.WeekFields` there are a couple of methods with a `newYearWeek` which increment the year by `1` on occasion. Why?

This is a strange bug.

Comment: see here http://www.journaldev.com/2800/java-8-date-time-api-example-tutorial-localdate-instant-localdatetime-parse-and-format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates):

> [YYYY] indicates the ISO week-numbering year which is slightly
>   different from the traditional Gregorian calendar year (see below).

1. `YYYY` is an ISO-8601 style representation of the year.
2. `yyyy` is the Gregorian year-of-era representation.

Since the the calculation of the two can be different by +1 or -1, hence the formatting. More useful info at [`YEAR_OF_ERA`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#YEAR_OF_ERA), [`YEAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#YEAR), and [`weekBasedYear`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekBasedYear).

Answer (score 0):

### There are FIVE problems in your code

**Problem#1**:

[`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) is not supposed to have time-zone information but you have formatted it in that way by forcibly putting a `'Z'` in the `DateTimeFormatter` pattern.

**Problem#2**:

Note that ['Z' is not the same as Z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953075/10819573). So, you should never use 'Z' in the date-time formatting/parsing API.

**Problem#3**:

`Y` ([week-based-year](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekBasedYear--)) is not the same as `y` ([year-of-era](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#YEAR_OF_ERA)). Check [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26431882/10819573) to understand more about the difference between these two.

**Problem#4**:

If all you need to specify is the UTC time-zone offset, you should use `ZoneOffset.UTC`. A `ZoneId` is more appropriate to specify a [time-zone ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in the *Region/Time-zone-reference-city* format e.g. `Europe/London`.

**Problem#5**:

You do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` for the output you want. The `java.time` API is based on **[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)** standards and therefore the [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) implementation of a `java.time` type returns a string in ISO 8601 format by default. All you needed is the [string representation of `Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--):

```
String output = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1451438792953L).toString();
```

The `Z` (stands for Zulu) in the output represents a date-time in UTC and has a `ZoneOffset` of `+00:00`.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String output = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1451438792953L).toString();
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2015-12-30T01:26:32.953Z
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.