# clojure java-time - date moves forward a year?

Tags: clojure, java-time

I'm confused on usage of the [clojure.java-time](https://github.com/dm3/clojure.java-time) library usage that wraps Java 8's java.time api.

I want a function that translates a date in string format from
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" format to "MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss a" format.

Here's my function:

```clj
(require '[java-time :as jt])

(defn change-ds-format [in-ds]
  {:pre [string? in-ds ]}
  (let [input-format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"  
        output-format "MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss a"]
    (->> in-ds
         (jt/local-date-time input-format)
         (jt/format output-format))))
```

This looks ok:

```
(change-ds-format "2019-12-28T00:00:00" )
;=> "12/28/2019 12:00:00 AM"
```

I have no idea why this is pushed to 2020?

```
(change-ds-format "2019-12-29T00:00:00" )
;=> "12/29/2020 12:00:00 AM"
;; Why is this one 2020 ???
```

I thought maybe it was a timezone offset issue but there is no way it should be shifting to the year 2020 I don't believe.

Comment: By the way, your first format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" (standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format) is used by default by the `LocalDateTime` class. No need to specify a formatting pattern explicitly. In Java syntax, `LocalDateTime.parse( "2019-12-29T00:00:00" )`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Y returns 2012 while y returns 2011 in SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686331/y-returns-2012-while-y-returns-2011-in-simpledateformat) Or this? [Why does Java's java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter#format(LocalDateTime) add a year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521733/why-does-javas-java-time-format-datetimeformatterformatlocaldatetime-add-a-y)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `yyyy` is not `YYYY`

From [Oracle docs for DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
 ... snip...
u       year                        year              2004; 04
y       year-of-era                 year              2004; 04
...snip...
Y       week-based-year             year              1996; 96
w       week-of-week-based-year     number            27
...snip...
```

I'm not very proficient at datetime arithmetic or the nuances but I believe that in week-based year counting this December's 30th and 31st are counted as year 2020 because these dates belong to week #1, not week #52 or #53.