# Why does formatting a date using DateTimeFormatter with a YYYY pattern give the wrong year?

Tags: java, time, date-formatting

Using `DateTimeFormatter` (with the pattern below) with a `LocalDate` results in the wrong year.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-d-YYYY");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2018, 12, 31);

date.format(format); // returns 12-31-2019 (expected 2018)
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This happens because the pattern `MM-d-YYYY` isn't what we think it is.

If we look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#Patterns) we see

```
 Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples  
 ------  -------                     ------------      -------  
 y       year-of-era                 year              2004; 04  
 Y       week-based-year             year              1996; 96
```

So `YYYY` is using the week-based-year, when we actually wanted `yyyy`, the year-of-era.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431882/difference-between-year-of-era-and-week-based-year) or [the Wikipedia article on week dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) for the difference.

So the pattern we want is `MM-d-yyyy`.

Comment: We had a java program that ran fine for 8 months, and then failed the last week of the year because of the YYYY issue.  (The last week being between Christmas and New Years, when half of the devs were on vacation.)  I changed the YYYY to yyyy and it gave me the correct year.  Thanks kag0

Comment: This blog post has a good code example of the difference between YYYY and yyyy - 
http://dangoldin.com/2019/01/06/javas-simpledateformat-yyyy-vs-yyyy/