# LocalDateTime formatter changing year from 2020 to 2021?

Tags: java, localdatetime

I am trying to take a date formatted String, parse it to LocalDateTime, then format it back to a String for display. What I found when doing this is that the original string is year 2020 and the LocalDateTime object also has the year 2020. But when I format the LocalDateTime for display, this String somehow is now year 2021?  Here's the code:

```
public class LocalDateTimeTry {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String originalData = "2020-12-29T20:01:06+0000";
    
    DateTimeFormatter originalFormatter = 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxx");
        
    LocalDateTime originalParsed 
        = LocalDateTime.parse(originalData, originalFormatter); 
    
    DateTimeFormatter displayFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, YYYY");
    
    String displayFormatted
        = displayFormatter.format(originalParsed);
    
    System.out.printf("Original String of data : %s%n", originalData);
    System.out.printf("LocalDateTime.toString(): %s%n", originalParsed.toString());
    System.out.printf("Formatted for display   : %s%n", displayFormatted);
}
}
```

The output looks like this: See how the year changes from 2020 to 2021.

```
Original String of data : 2020-12-29T20:01:06+0000
LocalDateTime.toString(): 2020-12-29T20:01:06
Formatted for display   : December 29, 2021
```

Any thoughts??

Comment: You want `yyyy`, not `YYYY`.

Comment: Oh man, ya of course. I should have seen this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andy Turner pointed out in the comments, the problem comes from this statement:

```
DateTimeFormatter displayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, YYYY");
```

where, according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), `Y` means a `week-based-year`, `y` means `year-of-era`, and `u` means simply `year`.

Therefore, these two variants should produce the correct year for you:

```
DateTimeFormatter displayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter displayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, uuuu");
```

Now to understand why `y` and `Y` are different and why do they lead to your problem, I found this already discussed here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62690443/9698467