# Bug in java LocalDate for Date Format

Tags: java, localdate

I was running some code and was getting a strange error I could not understand.
So i tried to debug it and ran multiple test and found this
this is the code I am running

```
@Test
public void test(){

    LocalDate firstDay = LocalDate.parse("2020-12-01");
    LocalDate lastDay = LocalDate.parse("2020-12-31");

    String firstDayString = firstDay.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMdd"));
    String lastDayString = lastDay.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMdd"));

    System.out.println(firstDayString);
    System.out.println(lastDayString);

}
```

And this is the output

```
20201201
20211231
```

please note the year for the last date changed to 2021 when i tried to do the format.
Any one else has notice this?

Comment: You should use `yyyy` not `YYYY` - Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26431882/150978

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your format is incorect if you are expecting 2020 for both dates. Change it to `yyyyMMdd`

- y (lowercase) is year
- Y (uppercase) is 'week-based-year'

Worth a read: [yyyy-vs-yyyy-the-day-the-java-date-formatter-hurt-my-brain](https://dev.to/shane/yyyy-vs-yyyy-the-day-the-java-date-formatter-hurt-my-brain-4527)

Comment: 20 years developing in java and first time i notice this

Comment: @rread A) one never stops learning and b) working with date and time always brings new surprises. I was working with the ethiopian calendar last week, which has 13 months per year, to implement an adapter in java,