# Convert from String to either LocalDateTime or ZonedDateTime

Tags: java

Hi I want to convert String value `2020-12-16T19:20:30+01:00 UTC` to either `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` in java

I tried solution:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD", Locale.ENGLISH);
final String responseTimeStamp = "2020-12-16T19:20:30+01:00 UTC";
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(responseTimeStamp, dtf);
```

Which gives me the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern letter: T at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.parsePattern(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:1815) at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendPattern(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:1712) at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DateTimeFormatter.java:588) at learning/learning.SpringDemo.main(SpringDemo.java:21)

Comment: What is wrong with `ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(responseTimeStamp);`? The format is standard. Your error was that you needed to quote the T: `...'T'...` and hh (12 hours) must be `HH` (24 hours). and YYYY (week year) yyyy (calendar year) and dd

Comment: As per your suggestion, i tried DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssTZD", Locale.ENGLISH);
  
  final String responseTimeStamp = "2020-12-16T19:20:30+01:00 UTC";
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(responseTimeStamp, dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt); But i am still getting the same error

Comment: TZD is suspicious. Just look into the javadoc on the internet for [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime
.parse( 
    "2020-12-16T19:20:30+01:00 UTC"
    .replace( " UTC" , "" )
)
.withZoneSameInstant( 
    ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) 
)
```

## ISO 8601

Your input string:

> 2020-12-16T19:20:30+01:00 UTC

… nearly complies with the ISO 8601 standard for data-exchange date-time formats. To fully comply, delete the SPACE and `UTC` from the end. The `+01:00` at the end means “one hour ahead of UTC", so the UTC at the end is redundant.

String input = "2020-12-16T19:20:30+01:00 UTC".replace( " UTC" , "" ) ;

## Offset versus time zone

Parse as an `OffsetDateTime` because your input indicates small offset from UTC, not a time zone.

An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead/behind the prime meridian of UTC. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians. A time zone has a name in format of `Continent/Region`, such as `Europe/Paris` and `Africa/Tunis`.

## `OffsetDateTime`

So the other Answer’s **suggestion to use `ZonedDateTime` for parsing is misguided** as no time zone is indicated. Your input has only an offset, therefore use `OffsetDateTime`.

No need to specify a formatting pattern. Our modified input complies with ISO 8601, and the *java.time* classes use those standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

## `LocalDateTime`

You asked how to get a `LocalDateTime`. That class lacks any concept of offset or time zone. So beware, if you convert from `OffsetDateTime`, you are discarding valuable information.

So while I don’t recommend doing this, here is the code.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = odt.toLocalDateTime() ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

You asked how to adjust into a time zone.

To adjust from our offset to a time zone, merely specify the desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.withZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong with your code. I suggest you to take a look at the DateTimeFormatter documentation.

1. **YYYY** -> This means week-based-year, you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431882/difference-between-year-of-era-and-week-based-year) to see the difference between year-of-era. So you should be using **yyyy**.
2. **DD** -> This means day-of-year, so December 16 is equal to 350. In your case you want to use **dd**, day-of-month.
3. **T** -> There isn't a pattern for T, so you can put it like a text to formmat you date **'T'**
4. **TZD** -> I don't know what you are trying to use here and I couldn't find the patter **+03:00 UTC**, you can try to use **O**

So your final pattern should be `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssO"`. It doens't work for **UTC** and I couldn't find it on ZoneId list, maybe because **UTC** is **+00:00** already, so **UTC+01:00** is equal to **+01:00**.

After a lot of working understanding the pattern, I found out that you are looking for `ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`, so you could just change your code like below:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME;
final String responseTimeStamp = "2020-12-16T19:20:30+01:00";
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(responseTimeStamp, dtf);
```

Comment: Thank you, Maickeen I have done so as of now, as i don't have production data to test. In sample data, UTC was mentioned, so i was trying that. ALso, what about String 2020-10-21 03:59:00 ?