# Unable to convert String to LocalDateTime format "YYYYMMDDhhmmss" (week year) pattern with (day of month)

Tags: java, date-format

I'm getting the "DateTimeParseException" when parsing the given String:

I know using 'yyyy' and 'dd' are suggested on some questions, but i can't use them.
I use JDK 17

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.*;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMDDhhmmss");
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("20120823151034", formatter);
```

Result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20120823151034' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Comment: `151034` would suggest that the pattern needs to be `HHmmss`

Comment: So, using Java 17, `yyyyMMddHHmmss` works for me. *"using 'yyyy' and 'dd' are suggested on some questions, but i can't use them. I use JDK 17"* - sorry, but that doesn't make sense to me, the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) clearly state that they are valid patterns

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431882/difference-between-year-of-era-and-week-based-year ?

Comment: *"I know using 'yyyy' and 'dd' are suggested on some questions, but i can't use them."*  You should edit the question to explain *why* you can't  use them.

Answer (score 3):

> I know using 'yyyy' and 'dd' are suggested on some questions, but i
> can't use them.

Not only 'yyyy' and 'dd', you also need to use 'HH' instead of 'hh' because 'hh' makes sense only with am/pm marker i.e. for a 12-hour time format. For a  time with an am/pm marker, you need to use 'hh' along with 'a' e.g. 'hhmmss a'. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to learn more about them.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse("20120823151034", formatter);
System.out.println(dt);
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2012-08-23T15:10:34
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/iYpIXM)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Good catch on `HH` vs `hh`